# Do Advanced Form and Terrible Form interact how I think they do?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Terrible Form is a style merit that lets you gain a modification,  then a technology, then a propulsion and finally an extra process.

It seems designed this way to limit early access to the more powerful propulsions and processes.

Advanced form lets you swap a modification or tech,  for a propulsion/process. This balances out as you lose access to one form aspect and have to spend a merit.

But at two points total you can get a propulsion or process, by combining the two, and circumventing the latter style merit tiers.

Is this an acceptable use of the two merits!? Does that follow rules as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Terrible Form gives you more form abilities than you can shake and shakey thing at a thing that shakey thing get shaken at.

I think it was there to allow a charater to gain one extra propulsion/process without needing to get more mods and techs. I feel this was intended (or if not that onxy path would like the idea).

One thing I do know from the people of Onxy path is that they believe in your game, your way (tm). This is not D&D where every action you can do has a rule, so it more about in the end of the day if you are ok with it or if you feel it breaks the game.

Not mechainics wise, if a demon can fall (being a starting charater) with a extra modification, technology, propulsion and process, then why can one have two proccesses